# QUrl: Protocol "sftp" is unknown

Tags: c++, qt, protocols, qnetworkaccessmanager, qurl

I am trying to LIST my sftp server, but I’ve got a problem when sending my request:
if I print my `QNetworkReply::errorString()`, this is what I get:
Protocol “sftp” is unknown

This is what my QUrl looks like:

> sftp://username:password@host:22

username/password is ok, the host and port are the one required for my server, so I don’t know what’s going on…
I tried with different schemes (http, https, ftp, sftp…) and it looks like only http and https is recognised…

Any Ideas?

Comment: Qt itself does (to the best of my knowledge) not support SFTP. You might have a look at this though https://github.com/lvklabs/QSsh

Comment: Tanks for the answer. I took a look at QSsh. It sounds great, but I cannot compile it... I'm currently using Qt5.0.2, so I downloaded Qt4.7.4 (according to QSsh's README file), but when I try to build QSsh, It is searching for the Qt libraries/Includes/specs in the wrong folder..
How can I change the way QSsh searches for Qt?

Comment: This is my exact compile error when I launch the "make" command:


    In file included from /home/bruno/Downloads/QSsh-    master/src/libs/3rdparty/botan/botan.cpp:8:0:
    /home/bruno/Downloads/QSsh-master/src/libs/3rdparty/botan/botan.h:11:20: fatal error: QtGlobal:   No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[4]: *** [.obj/release

Comment: Did you check the prerequisites Bruno? `Qt 4.7.4 (May work with older versions)`. Use Qt4 instead.